# How would I call variables from one method to another method?

Tags: java

How can I put the variables of "ab, bc, cd, & da" of dsada() method into the 123132 method without copying and pasting? (the *dsada** method also has a method from distance inside it too)

Comment: You declare and initialize variables but they are immediately thrown away because you don't do anything to them.

Comment: How are these methods related?  You could pass the variables to `isSquare`, return them from `order` to pass them to `isSquare`, make them class-level variables, etc.  It's not clear what the structure of this code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save those variables in the class scope.
Declare the variables, and make sure you initiallize them before you use them otherwise you'll get a NullPointerException.

Comment: May you please edit your post to remove the code portion for me please (school requires me to)? your answer helped alot, but I would appreciate it and I would still mark this as an answer.

Comment: Sure. Here you go